How to consume credentials from a service connection in Azure DevOps SDK and use them to connect to an AWS account?
I'm developing a web extension and I'm trying to consume credentials from a service connection using the Azure DevOps SDK. My goal is to use these credentials to connect to an AWS account. Here is the code I'm working with:
I am able to retrieve the service connection, but I am unsure how to extract the necessary credentials from serviceConnection to use them for connecting to an AWS account. Is it possible to achieve this using the Azure DevOps SDK? If so, could you provide an example or guidance on how to proceed?
import { getService } from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";

export async function consumeServiceConnection() {
    console.log("Consuming service...");

    try {
        const serviceConnection = await getService<any>('8e074b6-599-4eb8-b7c7-e98f78202e0');
        console.log("Credentials", serviceConnection);

        // Additional logic to use the credentials for AWS connection
        // ...
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting the service:', error);
    }
}


For the extension, Can you confirm the type with us? An Azure DevOps Web Page, Pipeline task or other? If you are trying to developer a task, you can check this extension sample:https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/blob/master/src/tasks/AWSCLI/TaskOperations.ts

The extension I am developing is a web extension

I am afraid that the credentials of the Service Connection can not be directly extracted in the web extension. The AWS service connection contains the secret token value.  It is not directly exposed in the return response of Service connection. To get the credentials, you need to process it in the task.

So, I need to connect with an AWS account, with this web extension, which you recommend, where I should save the secrets, other than a key vault
